# How to start a cron job using schedule:run manually in Laravel 5 (October CMS actually)

Tags: laravel-5, cron, laravel-artisan, octobercms

I know how to run cron jobs on Linux server, 
I know how to use $schedule->command('foo')->daily(); 
I have read this document many times https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan

But my question is where shall I write this line exactly 
$schedule->command('foo')->daily();? 
and what is $schedule variable actually? I mean is this any predefined variable in parent classes to which we can directly call if not which class we shall include in our file and how to instantiate this $schedule object.

My main concern is what is the elegant way to schedule jobs, what is the point of writing this in code where i am writing my logic because this line should run once in lifetime if I am not wrong because this will then push the job in Jobs table and then 
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1 should take care of it for rest of the lifetime

then where exactly I shall write such code which will run only once while we deploying the application on the server before starting the main cron schedule:run.

Please, someone guide me why there is no written document for how to run a scheduled task manually without writing it in a code which will be called many time during execution of a real world web application.

Answer (score 3):

First, unless you're actually using Laravel 5.0, specifically, you'll want to make sure you're looking at the right version documentation (and if you are using 5.0, specifically, I highly recommend upgrading, as it's long out of support). The current version (as of this writing) [is 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5), and October CMS has been updated accordingly.

As to your question, if I'm understanding you right, you don't want a *scheduled, repeating* job, but simply [an Artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan). To write an Artisan command, you create a class in the `Console/Commands` folder (this can be generated with the `make:command` Artisan command) and register it in `Console/Kernel.php`. You can then access it by running `php artisan your:command` (where `your:command` is the name you've chosen for your command).

If you want to schedule a repeating job, you put that `$schedule` line into `Console/Kernel.php`. The `$schedule` variable is imported through Laravel's dependency resolver.

If you have a deployment script that you use, and you want to call that single command programmatically, you can do so [with Artisan::call()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands), within your deploy script (be sure to import the Artisan facade):

```
Artisan::call('your:command');
```

Comment: Thanks Shauna for your reply, well you got me right I want to schedule a task but didn't want to repeat the process of scheduling it again and again everytime the script is being called,

Comment: Thanks Shauna for your reply, well actually I want to schedule repeating job but didn't want to repeat the process of scheduling it again and again everytime the script is being called, So I can't use Artisan::call('your:command'); in deploy script. However I wish I could use $schedule in my deploy script. anyway there is no such file as Console/Kernel.php in OctoberCMS so I will have to use registerSchedule method inside the Plugin registration class.

Answer (score 1):

Three Steps to take:

1) Set up cron task
http://octobercms.com/docs/setup/installation#crontab-setup

> Cron will call the command scheduler every minute. Then October evaluates any scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due.

2) Make your console command
http://octobercms.com/docs/console/development
This command can be executed manually on the command line. And can be executed on scheduled time as explained next.

3) Register a schedule for the newly made console command in the Plugin registration class
http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/scheduling#defining-schedules

```
class MyPlugin extends PluginBase
{
    [...]

    public function registerSchedule($schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('cache:clear')->daily();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

1. Upgrade to Laravel 8 (that is how I tested it)
2. run `php artisan schedule:list` - see what you have
3. run `php artisan schedule:test` - you will be given options

   ```
   Which command would you like to run?:      
     [0] App\...
     [1] App\...
   ```

then you type a number and see it is working