# Scheduled command controled by settings

Tags: php, laravel

I want to command enabled when running manually but disabled in scheduler:

```
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $settings = $this->app->make(Settings::class);
        if ($settings->get('COMMAND.ENABLED')) {
                $schedule->command(Command::class)->hourly();
        }
    }
```

Is any way to move this logic to class 'Command'?

Comment: Here is your answer please check the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176603/how-to-start-a-cron-job-using-schedulerun-manually-in-laravel-5-october-cms-ac

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start a cron job using schedule:run manually in Laravel 5 (October CMS actually)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176603/how-to-start-a-cron-job-using-schedulerun-manually-in-laravel-5-october-cms-ac)